# Declarations for enums, and structures

Tags: c, c89

I have wrote some files: main.c, functions.c, functions2.c, and header.h. The some functions in the functions.c, and functions2 use my some enums, and structures.

Where must I place my enums, and structures? How to write declarations for them in the functions.c, and functions2.c? My functions (from different files) have to see them.

For example, I have wrote such function's declarations in the header.h:

```
int func(void);
void func2(int);
```

But I don't know how it write for enums, and structures.

Regards

Comment: have you thought about a *header file* (maybe the same one where your prototypes are located), then including that in your `.c` files ? ?

Comment: @WhozCraig If I place it in the header file, then definitions of my enums, and structures will copied in the each .c-file. Will I have problems in this case in the future?

Comment: @Bush use header guard : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: @Bush abim has commented on, and answers below have included, using header guards to ensure multiple inclusion of header data is only pulled into a source file once. Between that and the proper syntax of declaring enums and structs, you should be good to go.

Comment: @Bush And even a header guard isn't necessary. What we are talking about here are declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example for functions.c:

```
#include "header.h"

int func(void)
{
 ...
}

void func2(int)
{

}
```

Example for header.h:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

int func(void);
void func2(int);

enum eMyEnum
{
 eZero = 0,
 eOne,  
 eTwo
};

struct sMyStruct
{ 
 int i;
 float f;
};

#endif
```

Comment: If I place it in the header file, then definitions of my enums, and structures will copied in the each .c-file. Will I have problems in this case in the future?

Comment: No, this is not the definition, only the declaration.

Comment: Thank you! Now I calmed down.

Answer (score 1):

**Declaring structures:**

```
typedef struct <optional struct name>
{
   int    member1;
   char*  member2;

} <struct type name>;
```

Put whatever members you want in the struct in the format above, with any name you want.
Then you use:

```
<struct type name> my_struct;
```

To declare instances of the struct.

**Declaring enums:**

```
typedef enum
{
    value_name,
    another_value_name,
    yet_another_value_name

} <enum type name>;
```

Put whatever values in the enum as above, with any name you want.
Then you  use:

```
<enum type name> my_enum;
```

To declare instances of the enum.